# How to access other plugins in a plugin?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

In a component's `<script setup>` block, I can access plugins with inject().

But how can I access other plugins' `provide()` in a later-`use()`d plugin?

I hoped there would be `app.inject()` in the `app` object that passed to the plugin's `install()` function, but there is no such function.

Maybe I can use `_context` property of the `app` project, but it seems like a hack.

Comment: @Sarumanatee can you provide an example?

Comment: You cannot, but depending on what you want to do with the provided stuff, there might be other means.

Comment: I eventually implemented a module injection system that allows sort-of 'singleton' modules that can provide singleton data without actually using global variables, and then converted all plugins to that kind of 'singleton' modules. So now app.inject() is no more needed.

Comment: IMO, Vue will never build an official way for you to access other plugins inside ones. Because in the design perspective, if your plugin requires another plugin or some data from the app, it should explicitly request them as an `options` variable of the `install` hook. It's much easier for the user to know which data should pass to your plugin to make it work.

Comment: @Duannx how would you go about passing it to the options? If you have `app.use(plugin1)`, how do you pass what that plugin provides to `app.use(plugin2)` ? Like OP, the only place I found with that information was in `app._context.provides.plugin1stuff` which doesn't seem meant to be accessed.

Comment: @Sarumanatee You can `import {plugin1Data, plugin1Function} from 'plugin1'` and pass it to plugin 2 by `app.use(plugin2, {plugin1Data, plugin1Function})`

Answer (score 0):

I just used a callback in main.js to pass an object from a plugin to another plugin.

```
let _bus = null;
app.use(eventBus, { initListener: (x) => { _bus = x } });
app.use(backendBus, { bus: _bus });
```

Then eventBus plugin's install calls `options.initListener(some object);` and you can see that object ends up in backendBus plugin's options.

I guess instead of a using callback a plugin could modify the options object it receives and you could see those modifications in main.js but this looked better to me than using options as a two way messenger.